# jQuery inputToken library : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I try to use multiple values fields with tokenInput library but I receive the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined   at y
>   (jquery.tokeninput.min.js:2)   at A (jquery.tokeninput.min.js:2)   at
>   Object. (jquery.tokeninput.min.js:2)   at Function.each
>   (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)   at C (jquery.tokeninput.min.js:2)   at
>   Object.G.g.success (jquery.tokeninput.min.js:2)   at u
>   (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]
>   (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)   at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)   at
>   XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You might also find this useful when asking questions [mcve].

Comment: The issue is because whatever is before `.replace` is undefined.  As you've not included that or how you generate it, there's not a lot we can do to help.